# Angular js files corrupt when navigating between routes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes, navigation

Whenever I navigate between pages in angular. The structure of the pages are damaged.

For example, when I am in the home page every thing is fine .but once I navigate from the home page to for example the shopping page, then I re-navigate back to the home page, some files like the js files of the themes and of the sliders doesnt load and the page's structure are corrupted.

Does any one know how to handle this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @CommunityBot: I concur

Answer (score 0):

it's look like you try to do some vanilla javascript or jquery , but angular doesn't know it, you have two options:

1. try to do some similar package for example angular-responsive-carousel ...
2. use jquery inside your ngOninit in ts file => npm install jquery => at the top of ts file make this (declare var $) => switch all your jquery function inside ngOninit.

I hope it works.